# ASP.NET MVC get object Id with json

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using a jsonResult to receive some object Id, then I try to print in `console.log` by using `$Ajax` in view, but the console log is printing `undefined` instead of some integer value.

Controller action method is returning the id value correctly:

```
public JsonResult GetLastProcessVersion(int workflowId)
{
    var Workflow = db.Workflows.Find(workflowId);

    // getting the max process id from selected workflow:
    var lastProcessVersion = db.Processes.Where(x => x.WorkflowId == Workflow.Id).Max(y => y.Id);
    return base.Json(lastProcessVersion, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Then I try to call in Ajax function:

```
$("#btnVisualize").click(function () {
   $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("GetLastProcessVersion")',
         dataType: 'json',
         data: { workflowId: $("#WorkflowId").val()},
       success: function (res) {
           console.log(res.val);
        },
        error: function (ex) {
            alert('Failed to retrieve info.' + ex);
        }
    });
});
```

In console log the value is returning "undefined"

Comment: This looks more like a `GET` request than a `POST`, meaning you should pass the `workflowId` in the URL.

Comment: You should also look at the content of `res` in your Javascript, why have you assumed you have a `val` property?

Comment: true, in this example its looks a GET request but i want to use this ajax function to redirect in another page after clicking on botton, but first i need to find how can i get the object id to create url link.

Comment: @ DavidG probably this res.val would give me nothing, thats the reason im receiving undefined . I like to know how can i get the value correctly.

Comment: Well the JSON being returned for a serialised integer is just the integer, so `res` on it's own might work. But use the browser dev tools to inspect the value.

Comment: indeed, calling just res without .val will give the object id that i need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your server, the method `GetLastProcessVersion` is defined as "GET", and your AJAX is trying to "POST" back to the same method. I am surprised you didn't get a 404 or 500 server error because the method the AJAX tries to post back simply is not defined.

Your AJAX function should look like:

```js
$("#btnVisualize").click(function () {
   $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: '@Url.Action("GetLastProcessVersion", "YOUR CONTROLLER NAME")',
       dataType: 'json',
       data: { workflowId: $("#WorkflowId").val()},
       success: function (res) {
            console.log(res);

            let redirectUrl = '@Url.Action("RedirectMethod", "RedirectController)?v=' + res;

            // similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
            // window.location.replace(redirectUrl);

            // OR similar behavior as clicking on a link
            // window.location.href = redirectUrl;
       },
       error: function (ex) {
           alert('Failed to retrieve info.' + ex);
       }
    });
});
```